# How to optimize conditional statement in for loop over image?

Tags: arrays, loops, image-processing, vectorization, octave

I'm wondering if there's an indexable way of doing the following code on Octave, as it's iterative and thus really slow compared to working with indexation.

```
for i = [1:size(A, 1)]
  for j = [1:size(A, 2)]
    if (max(A(i, j, :)) == 0)
      A(i, j, :) = B(i, j, :);
    endif
  endfor
endfor
```

A and B are two RGB images that overlaps and I want `A(i,j)` to have `B(i,j)` value if `A(i,j)` is 0 on all of the three channels. It is very slow in this form but I'm not experimented enough with this language to vectorize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code can be vectorized as follows:

```matlab
I = max(A,[],3) == 0;
I = repmat(I,1,1,3);
A(I) = B(I);
```

The first line is a direct copy of your [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) conditional statement within the loop, but vectorized across all of `A`. This returns a 2D array, which we cannot directly use to index into the 3D arrays `A` and `B`, so we apply [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to replicate it along the 3rd dimension (the 3 here is the number of repetitions, we're assuming `A` and `B` are RGB images with 3 elements along the 3rd dimension). Finally, an indexed assignment copies the relevant values over from `B` to `A`.

To generalize this to any array size, replace the "3" in the `repmat` statement with `size(A,3)`.

Answer (score 2):

Not adding much here, but perhaps this will give you a better understanding so worth adding another solution.

```matlab
% example data
  A = randi( 255, [2,4,3] ); A(2,2,:) = [0,0,0];
  B = randi( 255, [2,4,3] );

% Logical array with size [Dim1, Dim2], such that Dim3 is 'squashed' into a 
% single logical value at each position, indicating whether the third dimension
% at that position does 'not' have 'any' true (i.e. nonzero) values.
  I = ~any(A, 3);

% Use this to index A and B for assignment.
  A([I,I,I]) = B([I,I,I])
```

This approach may be more efficient than the repmat one, which is a slightly more expensive operation, but may be slightly less obvious to understand why it works. *But.* Understanding how this works teaches you something about matlab/octave, so it's a nice learning point.

Matlab and Octave store arrays in [column major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) (as opposed to, say, Python). This is also the reason that doing `A(:)` will return `A` as a vector, constructed in a column-by-column basis. It is also the reason that you can index a 3-dimensional array using a single index (called a "linear index"), which will correspond to the element you reach when you count that number of elements going down columns.

When performing logical indexing, matlab/octave effectively takes a logical vector, matches each linear index of that vector to the equivalent linear index of `A` and decides whether to return it or not, based on whether the boolean value of the logical index at that linear index is true or false. If you provide a logical array `I` that is of a smaller size than `A`, the indexing will simply stop at the last linear index of `I`. Specifically, note that the *shape* of `I` is irrelevant, since it will be interpreted in a linear indexing manner anyway.

In other words, logical indexing with `I` is the same as logical indexing with `I(:)`, and logical indexing with `[I,I,I]` is the same as logical indexing with `[ I(:); I(:); I(:) ]`.

And if `I` is of size `A(:,:,1)` then `[I,I,I]` is of size `A(:,:,:)`, such that in a linear indexing sense it can be used as a valid logical index matching each linear index of `I` to the equivalent linear index of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`max()` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html#d122e803218) can take a single matrix and return the maximum value along a dimension

There's also the [`all()` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) that tells you if *all* values along a dimension are nonzero, and the  [`any()` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) that tells you if *any* of the values along a dimension are nonzero

```
A = reshape(1:75, 5, 5, 3)
A(2, 3, :) = 0;
B = ones(size(A)) * 1000

use_pixel_from_A = any(A, 3)
use_pixel_from_B = ~use_pixel_from_A
```

Now for each element of the 3rd axis, you know which pixels to take from `A` and which to take from `B`. Since our `use_pixel...` matrices contain `0` and `1`, we can element-wise multiply them to `A` and `B` to filter out elements of `A` and `B` as required.

```
C = zeros(size(A));
for kk = 1:size(A, 3)
    C(:, :, kk) = A(:, :, kk) .* use_pixel_from_A + B(:, :, kk) .* use_pixel_from_B
end
```